# ¿Cómo insertar datos en SQL Server en campo Identity, sin que deje espacios vacíos?

Tags: c#, sql-server

El problema es que estoy insertando datos en la base de datos desde C# y el campo `id` que tengo es `identity`, ya inserta y todo pero el problema es que cuando inserto un nuevo registro sigue una secuencia, ya que es autoincrementable ejemplo: tengo 5 datos en la base de datos `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` y lo que quiero es que al borrar el 3, el siguiente registro no sea el 6 sino que regrese al 3 que no deje espacios. O ¿alguna idea de como hacerlo o como podría conseguir ese resultado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La principal razón de utilizar un campo autoincrementable es la integridad de la información que se va guardando en las tablas, de esta forma, si eliminas un registro, el `Id` eliminado no volverá a ser insertado (a menos que lo expreses explícitamente con la instrucción `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable ON` y luego con `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Table OFF`) que funciona como si dijeras "**desactivar Identity**" luego "**activar Identity**", entonces, de esta forma cada que insertes un nuevo campo, tendrás que recuperar el `Id` siguiente. Suponiendo que realizas el `INSERT` a través de un `SQLCommand`:

```
int lastId = ...//lógica y consulta para obtener el último Id

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("CadenaDeConexion"))
{
    connection.Open();
    var query = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Table ON; INSERT INTO dbo.Table (IdentityColumn) VALUES (@identityColumn); SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Table OFF;";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identityColumnValue", lastId);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Lo cual, **pierde completamente el sentido** ya que la funcionalidad del `Identity` la desactivas para poder manipular el `Id`. Entonces, para lo cual te recomendaría que la columna `Id` no sea un campo autoincrementable y funcione como almacenamiento de un `INT`, o `BIGINT`, por ejemplo:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("CadenaDeConexion"))
{
    connection.Open();
    var query = "INSERT INTO Tabla (Id, Valor) VALUES((SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 FROM Tabla), 'Descripción del campo' )";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Con esto, podrás manipular el último `Id` y poder insertarlos sin que estés perdiendo el conteo.

Ahora, entendiendo el contexto anterior, para recuperar los `Ids` perdidos, lo puedes obtener con la siguiente consulta, suponiendo que tenemos una tabla llamada `Users` y el campo autoincrementable se llama `UserId`:

```
;WITH TablaIdsPerdidos (IdsPerdidos, maxid)
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS IdPerdido, (SELECT MAX(UserId) FROM Users)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT IdsPerdidos + 1, maxid FROM TablaIdsPerdidos
    WHERE IdsPerdidos < maxid
)
SELECT IdsPerdidos
FROM TablaIdsPerdidos TP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users U on U.UserId = TP.IdsPerdidos
WHERE U.UserId IS NULL
```

Ahora, solo tendrías que obtener el primer `Id` devuelto en la consulta y construir la funcionalidad con el primer ejemplo del `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable ON/OFF` si es que así lo deseas.